# Opencart : Automatically removing product option & values while updating product

Tags: opencart

I recently came across this issue on opencart version 2.1.0.1 where if you have quite a lot of product options set and update the product they end up removing some of the options. In my case out of 133 option values 50 was removed without any reason.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is later identified to be caused by low max_input_vars value in php.ini My default setup had 1000 which I later changed to 2000 and now the issue no longer prevalent :)